# Can a Plain Old Java Object/POJO have methods that deal with business logic other than getter/setter methods?

Tags: java, pojo

Can a Plain Old Java Object have methods that deal with business logic other than just the getter/setter methods?

I see possibly mixed answers for this so is there no rigorous definition for this? I know a POJO cannot implement an interface, extend a class, and not use annotation.

Comment: I think the "mixed answers" is correct, there really isn't a consensus on how a POJO should work, precisely.  I think you should design something good for your particular use case.  (And I disagree with not using annotations, that just seems wrong.)

Comment: *I know a POJO cannot implement an interface, extend a class, and not use annotation.* According to **whom**? Because every class extends `Object` if nothing else.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes obviously, every class extends Object indirectly, but I meant extending any other class. That is one of the known rules to be considered a POJO, you can search that up online as well.

Comment: [Plain old Java object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) *is an ordinary Java object, not bound by any special restriction*. You are adding a bunch of restrictions. Why? Now it's true you aren't **required** to implement an interface for a POJO. But nothing prevents or discourages it.

Comment: I saw some mention online that they have seen POJOS only have getter/setter methods to be truly "plain" even though this restriction is not mentioned in Wikipedia link you sent, hence my confusion.

Comment: Sounds like a Transfer Object or Value Object to me. Both of which could be implemented with POJOs. The main thing POJOs are used to describe is an alternative approach to EJBs and various ORM solutions where you were required to express relationships and transactional attributes through annotations and extending from special objects and given a list of things you [must not do](https://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/can_i_start_threads_in).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I see you edited your second comment to my question. Just to clarify, a class can use an annotation, extend, or implement an interface as long as it does not involve some external framework or library and be considered a POJO still? I think I understand your second comment now.

Comment: @kanod98306 Pretty much. Entity beans are a type of EJB. See [MF's POJO note here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/POJO.html).

Comment: Voting to reopen, while the question has some misconceptions, I think the core question is asking if a definition exists and what it would be. The comprehensive answer we have relies on references, does not seem to be based too much on opinion and provides value for future readers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be getting caught up in details of a formal definition that does not exist.

“POJO” is not a precise formal term. “POJO” is a catchy casual term [coined by Martin Fowler, Rebecca Parsons, and Josh MacKenzie](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/POJO.html) back in 2000. Specifically, their term was in contrast to the *Entity Beans* of [EJB](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Enterprise_Beans).

The idea of a POJO is an object that is **not enmeshed in a complicated framework**. Any experienced Java programmer should be able to read and understand the source code of a POJO without needing to learn some framework, and without needing to look up third-party documentation.

### Annotations

So, a POJO will generally have few annotations only because because Java bundles few annotation classes. Most annotations come from external frameworks. So if we are avoiding the complications of external frameworks, we are avoiding most annotations.

Personally, I would add an exception for one framework: [*Jakarta Bean Validation*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_Validation)). This framework is relatively simple, does not involve any elaborate involvement, and focuses on the validity/integrity of the POJO’s own internal field values. The validation rules are applied as annotations.

[Logging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logging_(software)) might be another framework exception. And maybe [Java Management Extensions (JMX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions) monitoring too.

Notice that all three of my own personal choices in framework exceptions are focused on the POJOs themselves, as opposed to orchestrating some elaborate involvement with other objects.

### Business logic

And, yes, a POJO can have [business logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic), especially regarding its own internal state, and regarding its need to communicate its changes with the outside world such as persisting data and notifying other interested parties.

Indeed, you can learn about:

- [*Hexagonal Architecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)) by [Dr. Alistair Cockburn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alistair_Cockburn)
  (and related variations, Onion Architecture, etc.)
- [*Domain-driven design*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) (see [book](https://www.dddcommunity.org/book/evans_2003/) by Eric Evans)

… to see how you can use POJOs as *domain objects* ([“business objects”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object), with core business logic) while keeping them separate and protected from various elaborate frameworks operating in other parts of your app.

### Data-only objects

Some classes are intended to simply carry data. All such data-only classes are POJOs. But not all POJOs are data-only classes.

I suggest you learn about [Data Transfer Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and Value Objects, as kinds of data-only classes.

If the main purpose of your class is to communicate data transparently and immutably, use the [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) feature in Java 16+. In a record, by default, the compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

---

And let me be clear: there is **nothing wrong necessarily with elaborate complicated frameworks**. They can be exquisitely useful, obviously. That's why they were invented. Each framework has a purpose and a place.

The term *POJO* was invented so that in discussions about programming and system architecture/design we can make the distinction between classes that are simple and not entwined versus those classes that are complicated and entwined.

Comment: So technically, if I wanted to, I could have a class extend another java superclass that does not use any framework and still consider the child class to be a POJO because this child class is not being enmeshed in any framework, just using another Java parent class?

Comment: @kanod98306 Yes, you could… if you truly keep it simple. And let me be clear: there is **nothing wrong necessarily with elaborate complicated frameworks**. They can be exquisitely useful obviously, that's why they were invented. But the term POJO was invented so that in discussions about programming and system architecture/design we can make the distinction between classes that are simple and not entwined versus those classes that are.

Comment: Nice answer. Maybe it's worth to mention that we don't have Value objects, objects with no identity, as such in Java yet (*luckily project Valhalla would bring them to the language*), to avoid readers confuse Value objects and records. Here's a reference on [Value classes in Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

Comment: i agree here, this sorts of breaks encapsulation as logic dependent  solely on this class need not be leaked outside